# How to change timeout on a form submit in ExtJs 4

Tags: extjs, extjs4

**Where should I change the timeout configuration for a form submit?**

Should it be in the definition of the class(form) and if so why isn't it listed a config in form xtype?

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel

Should it be in the submit action and if so where can I see the documentation about it?

I'm using ExtJs 4.2.1

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In the form creation or in the definition of a class that extends form.**

"Although not listed as configuration options of FormPanel, the FormPanel class accepts all of the config options supported by the Ext.form.Basic class, and will pass them along to the internal BasicForm when it is created."

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel